# simple scripting issues

Tags: url, variables

I'm new to shell scripting and have some simple question which hopefully someone can answer here. I have a script supplied by some one where a java function has this format:

```
#!/bin/sh
myCall() {
  file=$1

  cd /xyz/pqr/lmn/gqa/

  java -DServletURL=https://bps.hg2.com/bps/bpServlet XMLuser $file > $xlfile
}
```

In above the url portion has to be replaced by different url when needed based on user selection.

myCall function is called in script at least two times and the value has to change. The part XMLuser$ $file > $xfile remains same for ecah call only the https add ahs to be replaced. once script works, it will be used as cron to run against diff urls as needed.

I used simple variable and put it before myCall to determine url and then the scripts based on user selection but it didn't work.
the java -DServletURL=https://bps.hg2.com/bps/bpServlet XMLuser $file > $xlfile doesnt combine (java -DServletURL= urla XMLuser  $file> $xlfile)  to become a single unit to be used for server login.

```
$url=""
echo "Please select server - A, B or C"
read server
if $server = A; then
$url = "http://www.urla.com"
else $server = B; then
$url = http://www.urlb.com"
else $server = C; then
$url = "http://www.urlc.com"
fi
```

Please advise what I can change here. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

- the [conditions](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/tests.html) should be written against the test program (either test or [ ] )
- variables should be written without the $ on assignment and written with the $ mark on reference
- on assignment there should be no space between the variable-name, = and the value.

> ```
>  url=""
>  echo "Please select server - A, B or C"
>  read server
>  if [ $server = "A" ]; then
>     url="http://www.urla.com"
>  fi
>  if [ $server = "B" ]; then
>     url="http://www.urlb.com"
>  fi
>  if [ $server = "C" ]; then
>     url="http://www.urlc.com"
>  fi
>  # myCall $url
>  echo $url
> ```

mind you should you want a true if -else if - else construct then you can use elif

```
 if [ condition ]; then
      ...
 elif [ condition ]; then
      ...
 else
      ...
 fi
```